# iOS when receive a remote notification can we know it and do something?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

There is several situations when receiving a remote notification:

1. app is not launched at all
2. app is foreground
3. app is background

what I am looking for is that user haven't click the notification to launch or active the app. can we catch the receiving and do some thing in such three situation?

I know 2 is ok, how about 1 and 3, and how to do it? thx a lot.

somebody mentions widget or NotificationService? is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) to your app.

iOS will launch your extension (NOT your app) in background when it receives a push notification. Obviously what you can do inside an extension is fairly limited.

Comment: awesome,  so the answer is yes, right? cool，you show me the way. thx

Comment: The answer is YES for your NotificationServiceExtension (NOT your app).

Comment: I implemented Notification Service Extension, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to be notified when your app moves to the background: implement the `applicationWillResignActive()` method in your app delegate, or register for the `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` notification anywhere in your app. This particular notification is sent as soon as your app loses focus, meaning that it's triggered when the user taps the home button once (to return to the home screen) or double taps the home button (to enter multi-tasking).

Comment: :) sorry my poor English , I mean the remote notification.